# pulseaudio identifies SPDIF output as mono instead of stereo

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

On a Cubietruck ARM board with archlinux, pulseaudio creates a mono sink instead of a stereo/2 channels one:

```
Card #1
    Name: alsa_card.platform-sound
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 22
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "On-board SPDIF"
        alsa.long_card_name = "On-board SPDIF"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_simple_card"
        device.bus_path = "platform-sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/platform/sound/sound/card1"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    Profiles:
        output:analog-mono: Analog Mono Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 700, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-mono
    Ports:
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-mono
```

Using Alsa directly works as expected so what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to avoid device autodetection by commenting out `load-module module-udev-autodetect` and `load-module module-autodetect` and manually set up the sound card:
`load-module module-alsa-sink device=default:CARD=SPDIF channels=2 rate=44100 channel_map=left,right` in the default.pa configuration file.

Comment: you are a lifesaver!!! in my case I had to use the hw:1,0 syntax